# When I should use hub context in signalr

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, signalr-2

I am new to .NET SignalR. I see most of online SignlaR examples for beginners, in a custom Hub class, there is a straight forward way to create custom Hub methods in a derived Hub class without using IHubContext object in those Hub methods.  Under which circumstance should I use IHubContext object?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did any of the answers below answer your question or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer way to get the hub

```
DefaultHubManager hd = new DefaultHubManager(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver);
var hub = hd.ResolveHub("AdminHub") as AdminHub;
hub.SendMessage("woohoo");
```

This will resolve your to your concrete hub object.